# Bluetooth share an mp3 file between iOS when only one phone has the app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, bluetooth, gamekit

I am building an iOS app to match an android app that can send a raw mp3 file from an app to another phone that does not have the app. The file is store in the file structure.

I'd like to know if using GameKit or some other method will get me close to that. I need to send mp3 files such that the receiving iPhone does not need to have the app to store them in their iPod app.

Is this possible on iPhone? Or do I need to have both phones with the app installed?

Cheers

Comment: The Apple iPhone does not support receiving files via Bluetooth. Because of that it is not possible to receive file without an app. Also if you want to save the MP3 to device library, this is not possible too since you only have read access to the library.

Comment: Thank you, thats what I wanted to know. I'll mark that right if you put it in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Apple iPhone does not support receiving files via Bluetooth. Because of that it is not possible to receive file without an app. Also if you want to save the MP3 to device library, this is not possible too since you only have read access to the library.

But if you want to share files without using a client app you may upload the files to an HTTP based file sharing service and then you only need the URL at the client device.